# Facebook Credits Example on App Engine?

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, facebook-credits, credits

Are there any examples of using facebook credits on Google App Engine?

I found this blog post , but it's not complete
http://blog.suinova.com/2011/01/integrating-facebook-credits-api-into.html

I got the sample runwithfriends [example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) working on the App Engine, tried to expand it with Credits, no luck so far.

Also searched for the FB developer forums, got nothing.

Any resources you can point me to?

What's not working:
1) When I click on the "pay with Facebook" button, I get an "Application Error" , without any error code.
 -Checked the javascript console
 -Checked the fb app settings
 -Tried on local server and production server

2) The callback.py isn't complete, because i could not parse the signed request (no code available in py for me to learn from)

3) What I basically did was to add code from Suinova Designs (link above) to the existing Run With Friends app code. Didn't turn out as expected.

my code so far:

```
//payment_page.html
<html>
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th> </th></tr>
<tr><td>Something to buy</td><td>10 FC</td><td><a href="" onclick="return buyit();">
<img src="http://www.facebook.com/connect/button.php?app_id=215638625132268&feature=payments&type=light_l" />
</a></td></tr>
</table>

// javascript

function buyit(){
    FB.ui({
        method:'pay',
    purchase_type:'item',
    order_info:{
        item_id:'myitem',
                title:'Something to buy',
            price:2,
            description:'Whatever',
            image_url:'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png',
             product_url:'http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png'}
},

function(resp){
    if(resp.order_id) window.top.location='http://apps.facebook.com/runwithfriends trial'; else alert(resp.error_message);
});
return false;
```

}

```
//callback.py
class FacebookPaymentRequest(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    signed_request = parse_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'),conf.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
    payload = signed_request['credits'] #credits:{buyer:int,order_id:int,order_info:{},receiver:int}
    order_id = payload['order_id']
    method = web.request.get('method')
    return_data = {'method':method}
    if method == 'payments_get_items':
        order_info = payload['order_info']  #order_info:{item_id:'',title:'',description:'',price:0,image_url:'',product_url:''}
        item = simplejson.loads(order_info) #needs to convert JSON string to dict
        #check item,price,etc and reply
        return_data['content'] = [item]
    elif method == 'payments_status_update':
        status = payload['status']
        return_data['content'] = {'status':'settled','order_id':order_id}
        if status == 'placed':
            #just return settled status to Facebook, this may be called twice
            order_details = simplejson.loads(payload['order_details'])
            #check and log here
        elif status == 'settled':
            order_details = simplejson.loads(payload['order_details'])
            #order_details:{order_id:0,buyer:0,app:0,receiver:0,amount:0,update_time:0,time_placed:0,data:'',items:[{}],status:'placed'}
            buyer = order_details['buyer']
            item = order_details['items'][0]
            #now save this transaction into our database
        else:
            #may be refunded, canceled, log the activity here
            return_data['content']['status'] = status
    self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(return_data))
```

Comment: i decided to fund a small open-source initiative to implement credits on App Engine. Have a feeling that people are going to need this. The link is here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=340374#p340374

Comment: Can you expand on "no luck"? What problem, specifically, are you having?

Comment: just edited the post to show more mode. hope someone can advise!

Answer (score 0):

Your python code looks fairly normal so I would guess that you are simply having trouble with your authorization.  Depending upon how you authorize (a process a fair amount more complicated that the credits system), you are likely being given a signed request that is only partially authorized... meaning you are authorized to access only certain parts of facebook, but generally not authorized to access the active/logged-in user (i.e. me).

You can verify this by determining if you signed_request is a full 80+ characters (as opposed to around 40).  Generally I try to authenticate by deciphering the profile (signed_request), if that fails then I try to use a previously stored cookie, then if that fails I try to relogin the user.  I determine failure by placing try/except around my calls to get a "me" object through the GraphAPI.